# MySQL column to log when row was added

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there an easy way to add a column to a table that stores when the row was created? Also, is it possible to do this with a column storing when it was last modified as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create columns with a default value for when the record was created and you can create a column that updates when the record is updated:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    LastUpdated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: Isn't the ON UPDATE meant for FK's? Does this actually work? This is new to me (which doesn't mean it's incorrect, I've just never seen it before). *Update*:* A quick google quest seems to indicate this *should* indeed work. Cool. Haven't tested it myself yet though.

Comment: @AmusableLemur one caveat, I have updated my example to show this, It is not possible to have the current timestamp be the default value for one column and the auto-update value for another column.

Comment: Examples can be found here: http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201207/Blog/Automatically-Updating-Time-Stamp-Columns-In-MySql/

Comment: This related blog post was interesting: http://michaelkimsal.com/blog/mysql-using-two-timestamps-for-createdupdated-values/ It's a decent alternative, but sadly doesn't keep everything automated on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a TimeStamp column by having its type as Date and a default value as current_timestamp